# Calling a function within my class isn't working

Tags: python, class, function

```
class MyClass(object):
    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

Everything i have been reading here and on other websites that with this code, if i run `MyClass.f()` it should return with `hello world` but instead i keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Calvin\Desktop\CS_Semester_Project\testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    MyClass.f()
TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
myCls = MyClass()
myCls.f()
```

As error saying you f method require instance while you calling it like a static function
You can read more [about python classes in tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) in [methods section](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)

Comment: Explanation: Functions that have self as the first argument must be called on an object in object.function() format

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that `f()` must be called on an *instance* of type `MyClass`, not on `MyClass` itself.

You need to create an instance of `MyClass`:

```
obj = MyClass()
```

In this case `obj` would be an instance of `MyClass`.

Then you need to call `f()` on that object:

```
obj.f()
```

The error message is confusing because of the way that methods are called in Python. When you call `obj.f()`, `obj` is implicitly passed to `f()` as the first argument. That's why you have to write

```
def f(self):
    ...
```

`self` is going to refer to `obj` when you call `obj.f()`.

Knowing that, if you take another look at the error message:

```
TypeError: unbound method f() must be called with MyClass instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

It makes more sense. It says that `f()` was expecting an argument, (specifically an instance of `MyClass`) and didn't get one because tried to call it on a *type* rather than an *instance of a type*.